# Permutable Prime number

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

A prime number $\overline{a_1a_2\ldots a_n}$ is called a permutable prime number, if for any $\sigma\in S_n$, the number $\overline{a_{\sigma{(1)}}a_{\sigma{(2)}} \ldots a_{\sigma{(n)}}}$ is prime. For example 13 is a permutable prime number. Are there infinity many permutable prime numbers?

Comment: Do repunit primes like $11$ or $1111111111111111111$ (19 1's) count?

Comment: *Notation:* Are you trying to but a bar over the entire number in both instances? Instead of `\bar` try `\overline`.

Comment: @SammyBlack, thanks, I edited the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permutable primes are tabulated, with discussion and links, at https://oeis.org/A003459

I believe the answer to the question is that, at the present time, nobody knows.

Comment: thank you for your information and the link.